# Postfix maillog query

Tags: postfix

Hi can anyone help me interpret the following:

```
1./var/log/mail.log:May  6 14:18:46 mails amavis[1078]: (01078-05) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOutbound}, MYNETS LOCAL [192.0.1.187]:59800 <billing@anycomp.com> -> <anyone@anywhere.com>, Queue-ID: C1C166A0163, Message-ID: <65214142$38C94EE1$F7C7A2A0@C31FE9>, mail_id: JL87Nefgqfcw, Hits: 2.206, size: 479350, queued_as: 611F06A01C3, 498 ms

2./var/log/mail.log:May  6 14:18:46 mails postfix/smtp[993]: C1C166A0163: to=<anyone@anywhere.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=0.8, delays=0.24/0/0/0.56, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 611F06A01C3)

3./var/log/mail.log:May  6 14:18:47 mails postfix/smtp[1134]: 611F06A01C3: to=<anyone@anywhere.com>, relay=mail.anywhere.com[174.220.110.50]:25, delay=1.4, delays=0.05/0/0.47/0.89, dsn=2.0.0, **status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4B9D92B8088)**
```

I know the general gist. The user `'anyone@anywhere.com>'` are saying they didn't get the mail but it seems to have sent ok.

If it shows as status sent can I assume that its gone successfully from my end?

Comment: The server on the other side queued it with that number

Comment: Ok, so does that mean its reached their server and its up to it now to do the rest? My server has done its job?

Comment: That's what it means, the server on the other side accepted it, and gave you a receipt.

Comment: Good stuff. cheers Nick.

Comment: Just to add to this. Why would he be recieving a mail from say anyone2@anywhere.com and not from anyone@anywhere.com if they both come from the same domain. Both are showing exactly the same status=sent message in the logs.

Comment: That's another question entirely, probably they have some after queue filtering going on.. spam or maybe some policy that is causing the mail to be marked as spam or quarantined.

Comment: Thanks again Nick. Appreciate that my second question there is a bit vague.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have there is a receipt of reception from the remote server. With that Queue ID you can contact the admin of that server, and they can trace what happened to the mail after reception. That does not mean that the mail will arrive at the end user's inbox, but that the remote server accepted the message. There are still things that could cause the mail to not be delivered to the user's inbox, spam checks, mail policies, and many other types of filtering could be involved.